# How can I make my Flutter application visible to users with Gmail.com email addresses on the Google Play Store?

Tags: flutter, deployment, visibility, google-play-console, app-bundle

I have recently deployed my Flutter application to the production mode on the Google Play Store. The application is targeted for 177 countries and should be available to all users, regardless of their email domain. However, I have received feedback from users with Gmail.com email addresses that they are unable to find the application on the Google Play Store.

I have added the Gmail.com email addresses to the list of testers during the internal testing phase, but now that the application is live, it doesn't seem to be visible to all users with Gmail.com email addresses.

I have checked the settings for the application and made sure that it is published on the public production channel, targeted to all countries, and compatible with all Android devices. I have also reviewed the policies of the Google Play Store to ensure that my application is in compliance.
Is there anything else that I should be doing to ensure that my application is visible to users with Gmail.com email addresses? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How recently did you publish it?

Comment: @RobertSandberg it's today. when I tried to access  the application from the url  from my personnal account (@gmail.com)I got Sorry, the requested URL could not be found on this server. But with my organization account it works fine

Comment: And you published it with your organization account, and you are an internal tester with that organization account?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, just give it some time to propagate through the servers. If you find it with the account you've published it with, but not other accounts, then just give it time.